# Where are microsoft office options stored?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

Suppose I change in word the option "insert/paste pictures as" from "inline with text" to "square" (the example is taken from Word 2010, but I also need the answer for 2007).

Where is that option stored?

In a file? If so, which file? In the registry? If so where in the registry?

Comment: If I make changes to an option with file A open and save file A, then close Word, then create a new file, file B, the option is the same as I had in file A after changing. If I then again change the option back to what I had initially and close without saving file B, then open file A, the options are the same as I had in file B after changing.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and find out:

[image]

Set the "process name" filter to "Microsoft Office", the "category" filter to "meta write" and then change the options you want to change.

Comment: This seemed a really good solution, but oddly enough when I filtered in this way, I got nothing.

Comment: Did you try to filter for changed files as well?

Comment: No, I'll try that